# Storing API response in session

Tags: javascript, api, express, nunjucks

On POST of a page I'm trying to GET information from an API, return the output and store the results so it can be used across all pages. The method in which the API is called isn't the best but it's just for proof of concept rather than production quality. So here is the code at the moment:

```
router.post('/page-one/', function (req, res) {
  var options = {
    'method': 'GET',
    'url': 'https://api.information.service.com/company/<value>',
    'headers': {
      'Authorization': 'Basic <key>'
    }
  }
  request(options, function (error, response) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error)
    console.log(response.body)
  })
  res.redirect('/page-two/')
})
```

So this works fine, the console returns the right information. How would I then take this and use it across all pages? Say on page 2 my get is:

```
router.get('/page-two/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('/page-two/', {

  })
})
```

I'm using Express, Express Session, Express Writer and Nunjucks.

Comment: I don't know if you're aware, but you're redirecting immediately to `/page-two/` before getting `response.body`. Surely you should wait for `response.body`, then store it somewhere (session variable etc), then redirect to `/page-two/`

Comment: @JeremyThille Thanks, yes I did notice that, got to make that adjustment as well. At the moment I'm stuck on how to store the response.body as a session variable and then return that variable on a different page

Comment: Make a helper that will call the api to fetch data in /page-two route ... call that helper in /page-one/ and /page-two/ . if it string data than make use of `session`. if it is object data then you can make use of `req.locals`.